# Kaltura Port Numbers?

Tags: port, kaltura

Can anybody share me what are all the default Ports that Kaltura Video Server is using?

I need to know the port list because I need this Server to be placed behind Firewall and those certain ports will then be opened.

Answer (score 2):

- On the API, apps (KMC/Admin Console/MediaSpace) and Batch machines - Ports 80 (http), 22 (ssh) and 443 (https).
- If you need LDAP with MediaSpace, you'll need port - 636.
- You'll also need an email port (depending on what method you use) on the machine that will handle mail for your Kaltura server.
- If you plan on using a streaming server (e.g. Red5, FMS, Wowza) - you'll need 1935 (RTMP), 8088 (RTMPT), 5080 (Red5 Admin), 1936 (debug).
- If you're planning to use Remote Storage/Drop Folders - depending on your needs, you'll need FTP, SFTP, Aspera FASP, etc.
- If you'll use NFS - port 2049 (and possibly 111 for portmap).
- On your MySQL and DWH machines - port 3306.
- On your Sphinx machine - ports 9312 and 80.

Check out https://github.com/kaltura/ce-packager/issues/35 for install instructions.